# Matlab figure window is not showing up

Tags: matlab, figure

I cannot open a figure window in freshly installed Matlab 2015b on a new PC. It draws correctly in taskbar small preview windows, but when I am trying to open the figure window - nothing happens. Also, saving a figure to PNG file works normally. This applies to figure windows that are empty or have something plotted (by `plot`, `hist`, etc.) except if something is drawn with `imshow` - in this case figure behaves normally (at least it looks so).

I tried `set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'zbuffer')` but nothing changed.

PC specs:

- Windows 7 x64
- Gigabyte GeForce GTX 980Ti G1 Gaming with version 355.98 Driver
- Double Xeon CPUs

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. If you just type `figure()` does nothing come up?

Comment: Exactly. It shows up in the taskbar, but nothing happens on the main screen

Comment: And I cannot open it in any way - neither by clicking on it in the taskbar, nor by Alt-Tab etc. It just doesn't show up.

Comment: Could it be coming up outside your screen area?

Comment: If @David  suggestion is right, you can use Windows+Left (.. right etc.) to get the window bock.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, it works! Now, how can I fix it? And why it's not the case with `imshow`?

Comment: What is the output of `get(0, 'DefaultFigurePosition')`? How does it compare to `get(0, 'ScreenSize')`, not only in pixel values but also the monitor values? I'm not sure why `imshow` works when the others don't, seems like a good question for MathWorks technical support.